# How much time to approve my app on google play?

Tags: android, google-play, publish, google-play-console

I have released my first android app on google play two days ago but it has not approved yet. Is that normal? how much time will i wait more?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not specifically about programming, but approval wait time.

Comment: Please wait upto seven days. My app was approved on third or fourth day... it is normal friend

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the [`Publish an app support`](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334282?hl=en) you'll find

> For certain developer accounts, we’ll take more time to thoroughly review your app(s) to help better protect users. This may result in review times of up to 7 days or longer in exceptional cases. You’ll receive a notification on your app's Dashboard about how long this should take.

Comment: i did not receive a notification about how long this should take.

Comment: How long are you waiting it to publish?

Comment: about two or three days

Comment: Then, google has 4 days remaining to review your app :D